# Satellite potential energy zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, potential-energy

Satellite is at a numerical distance to the earth so by
$$-GMm/R$$
it must have a non-zero potential energy then how can it have zero potential energy?

Comment: How about reading this  https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circles/Lesson-4/Energy-Relationships-for-Satellites

Answer (score 1):

You can set the zero point for potential energy wherever you like. It is *differences* in potential energy that are physically important, not it’s absolute value. Indeed, it is not possible to measure absolute potential energy - even the formula

$$-\frac{GMm}{R}$$

for gravitationally potential energy is only a convention that assigns zero potential energy to a (hypothetical) point at infinite distance.

Comment: So what do we r obtain when we use the above formula for a satellite.

Comment: The potential energy of the satellite-Earth system.